# Making an API call in onPause()?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a screen in my app which displays data from an API. When the user is on the screen they can reorder the data, which I want to persist on the server.

Rather than making an API call every time the user reorders an item, I want to just make one call when they leave the screen.

What is the best way to do this? I'd ideally put it in onPause(), but I'm not sure whether I can ensure that the API call is always sent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `onPause` does always gets called it is not only called when the user leaves the screen but sometimes when they resume it as well.

It is also not a great design pattern to run I/O heavy actions on these events and you will also have many issues around getting the response to verify the API indeed worked correctly.

I would recommend that you use a started Service as your outbound point of contact with the server and APIs and since a Service also has its own process it will be alive even if your application isn't (but you still need to use a bg thread impl. because it impacts the UI thread if you don't).

A couple of friends and i have written a good example for that awhile back and you can still find it [here](https://github.com/RanNachmany/AndconLab).

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

Post HoneyComb onPause() is always called before the Activity can be killed.  See the lifecycle section of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) reference for more info.